# Is Sql Server 2017 Available on Azure Db?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a sql server database running on Azure. Is it possible yet to upgrade this to Sql Server 2017?

I have searched, but only found data on running 2017 in a VM.

I looked in the Portal, but I did not see any option for specifying the version of Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Upgrade" is the wrong word.  SQL Azure runs a newer version of SQL than SQL Server 2017. As such, even if were to get the file from SQL Azure (it is not exposed as a feature to do this), SQL 2017 would not be able to open it.  (A later version of SQL Server might be able to read it, however).  You are welcome to export a SQL Azure database using the Import/Export service to logically copy the database out.  You can also use Data Sync or other replication techniques to export the data as it changes.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/overview-import-export?view=sql-server-2017

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-get-started-sql-data-sync

Comment: As 2019-08-26 Microsoft states the version used in Azure SQL is v12 which corresponds with Azure SQL Server 2014 (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview#sql-database-frequently-asked-questions-faq)

Comment: yes, the version number is hard-coded for the version running in the cloud.  You should not assume it is running SQL Server 2014.  It is running something closest to SQL Server 2019 CTP 3.2 currently

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT, Azure SQL still has some behaviors from SQL v12(2014), like this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3025845/fix-the-transaction-isolation-level-is-reset-incorrectly-when-the-sql. So, it is confusing

Comment: What you mention is not specifically a feature of SQL - it was a bug in SQL 2014.  SQL Azure is closest to "vnext" of SQL Server all the time.  There are some behaviors in SQL Azure that are purposefully different than SQL Server, but to my knowledge this one is not one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The closest direct answer is:

> It is based on the latest stable version of Microsoft SQL Server database engine.

This is quoted from the first paragraph on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview

Additionally, if you are using SSMS 18, or Azure Data Studio, you should be able to change the compatibility level of the database to a higher level such as 150 for SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL database and AZure SQL Managed Instance use a different versioning than the On- premises product.

For example: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Aug  5 2019 05:50:58   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

The above version is from a Managed instance and Azure SQL also has same version :

[image]

As explained by Conor, under the hood it runs the latest possible SQL Server version.

If you want SQL Server 2017 specifically,the you might need to try Azure VM with SQL Server 2017 installed.

Answer (score -1):

As 2019-08-26 Microsoft states the version used in Azure SQL is v12 which corresponds with Azure SQL Server 2014 (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-database/sql-database-technical-overview#sql-database-frequently-asked-questions-faq)

It seems we have no upgrade option available.

Comment: The version number in the cloud is hard-coded.  You should not assume it is running SQL Server 2014.  (If it were it would be possible to get you a backup and you could restore it on a later version of SQL Server, actually).

Comment: I did not assume anything but stated two facts. 1st that Microsoft official documentation says it's current version it's v12 (which in fact corresponds with MSSQL2014) and that we have no upgrade available (which is also true because we have no control over upgrades). But it's true the actual Azure SQL it's not a v12 because you can use the Graph features from MSSQL2017. So Greg Gum probably can use Azure SQL, and it's inquiry about the upgrades was not the question he needed answered.

Comment: You are mixing various concepts.  SQL Server has a version number.  SQL Azure has an architecture version (v12 is the current) but has a hard coded SQL Server version number.  While the hard coded version number aligns with what SQL Server 2014 used, it is not the same as SQL Server 2014's exact version numbers other than the major number being the same.  We just stopped incrementing the version number on SQL Azure.  Upgrades are happening under the covers in SQL Azure without the major version changing).  v12 means nothing on SQL Server - it is a cloud-only construct